# How do the methods of the Scanner class behave when I try to take input numbers?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm studying the methods of the Scanner class, only each site says something completely different and I'm getting confused. My doubt is as follows:

Why is the following code:

```
System.out.println("Enter the number of wheels: ");
do {
    if (input.hasNextInt()) {
        numeroRuote = input.nextInt();
        // verificaTipoDiDato = false;
        break;
    }
        
    else {
        System.out.println("Wrong data type for number of wheels!\Enter new number of wheels: ");
        // verificaTipoDiDato = true;
        input.next();
    }
}
while (!input.hasNextInt());

System.out.println("Enter the number of headlights: ");
do {
    if (input.hasNextInt()) {
        numeroFari = input.nextInt();
        // verificaTipoDiDato = false;
        break;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Incorrect data type for number of headlights!\Enter new number of headlights: ");
        // verificaTipoDiDato = true;
        input.next();
    }
}
while (!input.hasNextInt());
```

It does this:

```
Enter the number of wheels: 
hello
Data type for the wrong number of wheels!
Enter a new number of wheels: 
hello
Data type for the wrong number of wheels!
Enter a new number of wheels: 
4  
Enter the number of headlights: 
Vehicle wheel number: 0
Number of vehicle headlights: 4
```

Shouldn't it also require input of the number of headlights?

I can't understand why.

Comment: Your loop ends as soon as `input.hasNextInt()`, without consuming `nextInt()`.